# Android NDK assert.h problems

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, assert

First one - is what NDEBUG somehow already defined by default, so asserts don't work until you #undef it. 
Second one - they do they work, but i receive no logging in DDMS.

If there is some android specific one assert.h?

Or i just do something wrong?

Comment: Whether `NDEBUG` is defined should depend on the compiler flags. If you compile in release mode, it should be defined, in debug mode, obviously it shouldn't. You can check (if your IDE settings don't answer that) by putting something like `#ifdef NDEBUG\n#error Oops, NDEBUG is defined\n#endif` (replace the '\n' with actual newlines) in a source file and compiling it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to compile your code with asserts then you can do it in three ways:

- use NDK_DEBUG=1 argument in ndk-build commandline
- add android:debuggable="true" to < application > tag in AndroidManifest.xml
- add APP_OPTIM := debug to your Application.mk file - this will also disable optimizations and will compile with debug symbols

Answer (score 6):

Usually program will crash due to `SIGSEGV` signal after `assert()` is called, by default `NDEBUG` is define, you may turn off by add the flag (`LOCAL_CFLAGS += -UNDEBUG`) during compilation but not work for my case.

I found another solution is using `__android_log_assert`, simply define as below and replace `assert()` with `assert3`:

```
#define assert3(e...) __android_log_assert(e, "TAG", #e)
```

Comment: -UNDEBUG actually worked for me.. Thank you very much

Comment: But why though? Why can't I use `assert` statements when building in release mode?