# How to know the gcc optimization level for ndk-build

Tags: gcc, android-ndk, makefile, java-native-interface, compiler-optimization

I was writing some native code on Android using NDK(jni).
I want to turn off the gcc compiler optimization.
For now I add `LOCAL_CFLAGS += -O0` to Android.mk, I'm not sure if it is working.

I wrote some code to test the loop overhead like this:

```
// gettime
for(int i = 0 ; i<10000;i++)
{

}
// gettime
```

The time difference is too small that I'm sure that the loop has been deleted by the compiler.
I can change `i` to a volatile variable, but I want to test if I have turned off the compiler optimization correctly.

How can I know the optimization level that is used by gcc(ndk-build), can I set `make` to verbose to get all the messages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 10k `inc`s is very likely to be done in 10k clock cycles. That's _really_ fast even on a "slow" processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See here how to disable optimizations: [Android NDK assert.h problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140423/android-ndk-assert-h-problems/9144080#9144080)

Basically what you need to do is to add

```
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

to your Application.mk file

Answer (score 6):

The compiler defines a macro named `__OPTIMIZE__` when optimization is enabled.

If you insert these lines into any C file, then the compile will fail if your make flags didn't work for that file.

```
#ifdef __OPTIMIZE__
#error Optimization enabled. That's not right!
#endif
```

Another possibility is to check the arch-specific flags on a built binary file (.o or executable).

```
readelf -A myfile.o
```

ARM has a flag that indicates the optimization level, but I think the Android toolchain might be a little old to use that correctly, so YMMV.

Comment: Yes, I check it with you code, the `-O0` is not working, compiler just throws the error message.  Then how to correctly turn off optimization for android-jni project?