# How keep asserts active for release build

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, assert

I am developing android application with cocos2d-x using c++.
I want to get asserts thrown for my release build.

I have [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140423/android-ndk-assert-h-problems) that it is possible 
by adding

1. android:debuggable="true" to < application > tag in AndroidManifest.xml
2. APP_OPTIM := debug to Application.mk file

But I want to achieve this without disabling optimizations, compile with debug symbols, or any other debugging or tracing facilities in the code.

How I can keep asserts active for release build without any other debugging or tracing facilities in the code. How to make such a configuration?

Comment: Standard `assert` behavior is governed by the `NDEBUG` macro symbol. The standard provides special support for defining or undefining this symbol in code and including `<assert.h>` anew. Which is guaranteed to redefine `assert` correspondingly (unlike the behavior of other headers).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf where I should define `NDEBUG` ?

Comment: Please don't define NDEBUG.  rather define assert for the modules you want, or in the precompiler headerslist.  Use `#undef assert` `#define assert(cond) ....`.  You can exit the app from there, and even write to a log file, using the __FILE__ and __LINE__ macros inside your definition of assert() to write crash info to a file.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy it is a big project I want to make all existed assertions to work in release build.

Comment: @TM: You can also change assert.h in your runtime headers to whatever you want .

Comment: The reason I say that is that NDEBUG may cause changes to other parts of the code, like selecting some debug options in allocation and in stl containers.  Changing assert() at the source is the fastest way to get the closest binary to the actual release version as possible.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy is android:debuggable="true" to < application > tag in AndroidManifest.xml equivalent to  defining NDEBUG?

Comment: No idea.  I'm mostly in the Windows or embedded world.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160099/discussion-between-t-m-and-michael-roy).

Comment: @MichaëlRoy: Defining or undefining a symbol from the standard library, other than where explicitly permitted, has Undefined Behavior (C++14 §17.6.4.3.1/1 “shall not”). Your idea that using the standard functionality can wreak havoc, sounds very much like FUD.

Comment: Even when the goal is finding the source of a bug ?  That's the usual use case for enabling assertions and traces in a release build.

Answer (score 1):

assert for android in cocos2d-x is defined as `__android_log_print` nkd function (in `CCPlatformDefine-android.h`)
you can redefine it with `__android_log_assert`

```
#include "platform/CCPlatformConfig.h"
#if CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
//Redefine CC_ASSERT for android with __android_log_assert

#ifdef CC_ASSERT
#undef CC_ASSERT
#endif

#ifdef CC_NO_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT
#undef CC_NO_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT
#endif

#ifdef CC_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT
#undef CC_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT
#endif

#include <android/log.h>

#define CC_NO_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT(cond)                        \
    if (!(cond)) {                                              \
        __android_log_assert(#cond,                              \
                            "cocos2d-x assert",                 \
                            "%s function:%s line:%d",           \
                            __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);  \
    }

#define CC_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT(cond, msg)                          \
    if (!(cond)) {                                                  \
        __android_log_assert(#cond,                                 \
                            "cocos2d-x assert",                     \
                            "file:%s function:%s line:%d, %s",      \
                            __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, msg); \
    }

#define CC_ASSERT(cond) CC_NO_MESSAGE_PSEUDOASSERT(cond)

#endif //CC_TARGET_PLATFORM == CC_PLATFORM_ANDROID
```