# Google Test: Android vs Linux EXPECT_DEATH Tests

Tags: android, c++, googletest

I am running into a problem while working on unit testing my system that I don't even know how to approach debugging. My code operates either on a linux machine with mock input or on an android device. I am using Google Test to run unit tests on it. I have it set up so that a call to "$ make all" will run my unit tests on both the linux machine and through adb shell on my device. This part is working fine.

However, when I introduce a test with EXPECT_DEATH(...) in it, the linux build runs the same as usual but the android build stops at that test and appears to freeze (I have to Ctrl + C to stop execution). As I said, I'm not at all sure how to try to fix this problem as I can't seem to get any output or error messages from it.

If you have any suggestions please let me know. If there is critical information I'm leaving out about my build, comment and I can add that in.

Edit:

When I run the function that I'm expecting to die outside of EXPECT_DEATH the same behavior occurs. This indicates that the assert in the function is working and EXPECT_DEATH is not doing what it should to handle that.

Before: (Works fine on Linux build but not on Android build)

```
EXPECT_DEATH(pObj->fxn(deathlyParam), "");
```

After: (Same result on Android build; core dump error due to assert on Linux build which is what I would expect both times from the Android build)

```
EXPECT_EQ(pObj->fxn(deathlyParam), 0);
```

For reference, fxn() looks something like this:

```
int fxn(int param)
{
   assert(param != deathlyParam);
   ...
}
```

In light of this, it looks more like assert is acting improperly and not causing the error it should be. Therefore, EXPECT_DEATH has nothing to expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. The problem was indeed arising from the assert in my function and not from EXPECT_DEATH. I don't know if this is just a feature of the project I'm working on (which had been developed for some time before I got to it) or if it is true of any Android build but NDEBUG was undefined, as in a release build. When I added "APP_OPTIM := debug" to my Application.mk file, it worked perfectly.

I am still a little confused why an assert would seemingly halt execution when NDEBUG is undefined. Aren't asserts supposed to be ignored entirely in release builds?

Credit to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140423/android-ndk-assert-h-problems) question and answer for the solution.