# Compile C++ program on Android: undefined function assert

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to compile my C++ program on Android but it won't compile because `assert` is undefined.

I've found a couple of hints online but none of them have worked:

I have set `APP_OPTIM=debug` in myApplication.mk

I have set `NDK_DEBUG=1` through parameters override, e.g.

```
externalNativeBuild {
  ndkBuild {
    arguments "NDK_DEBUG:=1"
  }
}
```

I have set the `android:debuggable="true"` attribute in my Android manifest document.

I have set the build types and toggled `debuggable` to true and false

```
buildTypes { 
    release {
        debuggable true
        ...
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        ...
    }
}
```

I don't know what else I can do. Assert is still being undefined. I must `#define assert ;` an empty statement to compile. I want to do it the right way.

Comment: are you using `ndk-r18b`?

Answer (score -1):

I am also using CMake and able to use assert.

[image]

I would suggest you to try creating new project from android-studio 'File->new project->Choose your project(scroll down and select Native C++)->Next->Next-Finish'. This will create android app with native component in it. modify the .cpp file of native component to use assert(include assert.h) and see if it works.

Also check if this post help you to resolve your issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9144080/4181904

Comment: I'm using cmake